# HighCharts Series Data Structure Issue. JSFiddle link provided

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

My HighCharts works fine with the data inside `data` as series, but I want to provide the data in a format like `data_New`. How do I change my HighChart settings to accept that format? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w9ddqyf4/1/).

```js
var data = [{
  name: 'Apples',
  data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
}, {
  name: 'Oranges',
  data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
}, {
  name: 'Plums',
  data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
}];

var data_New = [{
    name: 'John',
    Apples: 5,
    Oranges: 2,
    Plums: 3
  }, {
    name: 'Peter',
    Apples: 3,
    Oranges: 2,
    Plums: 4
  }, {
    name: 'William',
    Apples: 4,
    Oranges: 3,
    Plums: 4
  },
  {
    name: 'Chris',
    Apples: 7,
    Oranges: 2,
    Plums: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'Mike',
    Apples: 2,
    Oranges: 1,
    Plums: 5
  }
];


Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Stacked column chart'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['John', 'Peter', 'William', 'Chris', 'Mike']
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Total fruit consumption'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.percentage:.0f}%)<br/>',
    shared: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'percent'
    }
  },
  series: data_New
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: How do you change the library to fit your data structure? Why would you? Explain/demonstrate how you want your chart to be displayed, and we can tell you how to set up your data structure and chart config to achieve it.

Comment: Hi @jlbriggs, The intention of the question was not to change the library to fit my data structure. The data that is passed on to me is in a different format. So, Before i go ahead and reformat the data as required by the library. I wanted to check if there are alternatives ways to feed the data to the library. The chart i want to be displayed can be viewed in the JSFiddle link i provided in the question(if you pass data instead of data_New to the library). Thank you for your time for looking into this question. :)

Comment: Gotcha. There's no way around restructuring the data for Highcharts, but it looks like you have a good answer on an easy way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts accepts 3 types of datasets ([`Series`](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series)).

The simplest way in your case would be to convert your `data_New` to a structure Higcharts accepts, using  [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

Example:

```js
var data_New = [{
        name: 'John',
        Apples: 5,
        Oranges: 2,
        Plums: 3
    }, {
        name: 'Peter',
        Apples: 3,
        Oranges: 2,
        Plums: 4
    }, {
        name: 'William',
        Apples: 4,
        Oranges: 3,
        Plums: 4
    },
    {
        name: 'Chris',
        Apples: 7,
        Oranges: 2,
        Plums: 2
    },
    {
        name: 'Mike',
        Apples: 2,
        Oranges: 1,
        Plums: 5
    }];
    

var data = [{
  name: 'Apples',
  data: Array.from(data_New, function(a){ return a.Apples})
},{
  name: 'Oranges',
  data: Array.from(data_New, function(a){ return a.Oranges})
},{
  name: 'Plums',
  data: Array.from(data_New, function(a){ return a.Plums})
}]

console.log(data)
```

Your updated [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/websiter/gq78smh3/).

And if you have variable dataset structures, want to create categories from the first property and dataset from the rest, go a little more abstract:

```js
var data_New = [{
        name: 'John',
        Apples: 5,
        Oranges: 2,
        Plums: 3
    }, {
        name: 'Peter',
        Apples: 3,
        Oranges: 2,
        Plums: 4
    }, {
        name: 'William',
        Apples: 4,
        Oranges: 3,
        Plums: 4
    },
    {
        name: 'Chris',
        Apples: 7,
        Oranges: 2,
        Plums: 2
    },
    {
        name: 'Mike',
        Apples: 2,
        Oranges: 1,
        Plums: 5
    }];

// make categories from first property values
var firstProp = Object.keys(data_New[0])[0],
    categories = Array.from(data_New, function(x){ return x[firstProp] });

// make data from all properties except first
var data = [];
for (i = 1; i < Object.keys(data_New[0]).length; i++) {
  var prop = Object.keys(data_New[0])[i];
  data.push({
    name : prop,
    data : Array.from(data_New, function(x){ return x[prop] })
  })
}   
console.log('categories:',categories,'\ndata:', data);
```

The only condition is that all objects share the same data structure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry i do not have enough reputation to upvote your Answer. I will do it when i have enough reputation. :)

Comment: Don't worry, @Gokul. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily transform your data to format accepted by Highcharts with Array.prototype.map

```
// Transform your data into accepted format
var series = inputData.map((s) => ({
  name: s.name,
  data: [s.Apples, s.Oranges, s.Plums]
}))
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/vn8wnd1k/